# Typescript - wrapping functions while preserving signatures

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap defined functions so I can do additional work while preserving their signatures. Here's the desired effect:

Programmer defines interface:

```js
const actions = {
    first: (id: number) => {/*...*/},
    second: (name: string) => {/*...*/}
}
let actionsInterface = wrap(actions)
export actionsInterface
```

`actionsInterface` **should** (i.e. that's the goal) have the following interface:

```js
{
    first: (id: number) => void,
    second: (name: string) => void
}
```

It basically provides the same exact interface (i.e. same list of functions, with same parameters, not counting the return type) as it was first defined, but there is additional work that is being done, that was injected by the `wrap()`.

My current implementation is something like:

```js
type VarFn = (...args: any) => any

function wrap<T, K extends keyof T>
(funcList: Record<K, T[K] extends VarFn ? T[K] : never>) {

    // this maps a specific function to a function that does something extra
    function wrapOne<T extends (...args: any)=>any>(fn: T) {
        return (...args: Parameters<typeof fn>) => {
            someMagicThingyExtra(fn(args))
        }
    }

    // we iterate through the list and map each function to the one that's doing something extra
    type FuncMap = Record<K, (...args: Parameters<T[K] extends VarFn ? T[K] : never>)=>void>
    let map: FuncMap
    for (var Key in funcList) {
        let func = funcList[Key]
        map[Key] = wrapOne(func)
    }
    return map
}
```

However, I get a following error on `wrap(actions)`:

```
Argument of type '{ first: (id: number) => void; second: (name: string) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"first" | "second", never>'.
  Types of property 'first' are incompatible.
    Type '(id: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

So, for some reason, it didn't match `(id: number) => void` with `(...args: any) => any`, so it infered `never`.

---

So I tried a bit different thing:

```js
function wrap2<T, K extends keyof T, U extends VarFn>
(funcList: Record<K, U>) {

    function wrapOne<T extends (...args: any)=>any>(fn: T) {
        return (...args: Parameters<typeof fn>) => {
            someMagicThingyExtra(fn(args))
        }
    }

    type FuncMap = Record<K, (...args: Parameters<U>)=>void>
    let map: FuncMap
    for (var Key in funcList) {
        let func = funcList[Key]
        map[Key] = wrapOne(func)
    }
    return map
}
```

No errors, but my return type of `wrap2(actions)` is:

```js
{
    first: (...args: any) => void
    second: (...args: any) => void
}
```

...and I lost types of parameters, which defeats the whole purpose of trying to wrap the functionality, but preserving signatures (i.e. parameters' types).

Any help or guidance is welcome. Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Dragomir provided answer that completely preserves signature (both parameters' types and return types). My use case further needed to alter the return type to `void` and this is how I achieved it:

```js
function wrap<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any)=>any>>(funcList: T) {

    // this maps a specific function to a function that does something extra
    function wrapOne<T extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: T) {
        return ((...args: Parameters<typeof fn>): void => {
            someMagicThingyExtra(fn(args))
        })
    }

    // we iterate through the list and map each function to the one that's doing something extra
    type WrapMap = {
        [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>)=>void
    }
    let map: WrapMap
    for (var Key in map) {
        map[Key] = wrapOne(funcList[Key])
    }
    return map
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generic type `T` should have a constraint that all it's members are of type `VarFn` which you can easily so using `T extends Record<keyof T, VarFn>`. Since the returned type is exactly the same as the input type `map` can just be of type `T`.

```
type VarFn = (...args: any) => any

function wrap<T extends Record<keyof T, VarFn>>(funcList: T) {

  // this maps a specific function to a function that does something extra
  function wrapOne<T extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: T): T {
    return ((...args: Parameters<typeof fn>) => {
      return someMagicThingyExtra(fn(args))
    }) as T
  }

  // we iterate through the list and map each function to the one that's doing something extra
  let map = {} as T
  for (var Key in funcList) {
    let func = funcList[Key]
    map[Key] = wrapOne(func)
  }
  return map
}

const actions = {
  first: (id: number) => {/*...*/ },
  second: (name: string) => {/*...*/ }
}
let actionsInterface = wrap(actions)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=50&pln=3&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwGIDsoF4oAoB0fEDmAzgFxRwogCUGAfOZQLABQAZgK4oDGwAlgPZoi-ALYQAsnAK8uAFQAWvFARABRAB7AEcLAghF2AG2BkK1U5SgBvFgF8WHbn0FQA7trAAeWVAiaIKAAmRFAAShBc-AiBngDWECD8rFCyADSwiKi0tFiOXAAyvEQmKTQ2zCxQUAD01VDAiiEicGAhcFBEkFy8rDJQec5owPzk-Zw8AkPycMBQgfz6HaIQDUoEvpralWNOk24eAPIoEN4bwAHB2Hg4hKQM1HT3OawoZLJUb9bbVXrA7AhoLC4fAIYhkAAKiDgYnOCCInlAkCS-RQtBo6Ho5Sq2Kgv3+QmWkmkckUyjUmx0LywtyoVG+UFsNDgIVk23sFWYVVqbmgvFhM2gDQQ-HYBHk9Xk0EMRVmFECUGaYF8cC44oGe2GEuggkF02AAHIQvM1ksYaT1n4tHBtoYVgqWhhrLZyCztqwotgAG6IKAAaQSUCUOwKMrK9NtszyjryhWKAG1-SAALr0xUJhJJx3uFpHCC5cZ0zkM7Z4gH2sB2FgsSIoYrkCaCEKYLH9XhwkpYXiBMgodgiABGEAQ6Mx1QAVNcx3VbKltkQIoJu9gUNCIGRigg1iPrOPJ9PK8wI-XBkQAJIoWGsFXQTDZsDUhu1wtAA)

Comment: I am impressed that if manages to infer the correct type of functions instead of leaving them as `VarFn`. I guess extending entire `Record` instead of only its value part does the trick. This does manage to solve my problem. Once more thing, my returned functions should return `void` once wrapped. How that can be done? Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to succeed with changing the return type to `void`. Edited question to include it as well, and it was based on your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the first thing I landed on. It keeps even the generics of the wrapped function:

```
const newFunction = ((one, two) => {
    const result = oldFunction(one, two)
    // ...
    return result
}) as typeof oldFunction
```